# Starting transmission causes drive to unmount

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+

I have a drive with media files. It's mounted on `/media/pi/media`. The drive unmounts whenever I start the torrent client transmission. Why?

Details

- I have previously `run sudo chown -R pi:pi /media/pi/media/` and `sudo chmod -R 777 /media/pi/media/`. This is probably bad and might affect this issue, but I don't know.
- Transmission downloads to `/media/pi/media/torrents-complete`

Comment: "*Many bittorrent clients have the option of storing intermediate files elsewhere. That could fix your issue - storing all the little chunks on your local SSD, and then once the file is complete, transferring to your external HDD.*" || https://www.reddit.com/r/torrents/comments/8vs8t6/downloading_torrents_directly_to_external_hard/